# Getting a user's mailbox database in Exchange (2010) using C#

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I've been searching for a way to find out a user's mailbox database in Exchange and have not found anything other than powershell scripts.  I did find an autodiscover service that I thought would work but I'm not getting the response I thought I would.

```
        try
        {
            AutodiscoverService autodiscoverService = new AutodiscoverService("mynetwork.ext",ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
            autodiscoverService.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Administrator@mynetwork.ext", "mypassword");

            // Get the user settings.
            // Submit a request and get the settings. The response contains only the
            // settings that are requested, if they exist. 

            GetUserSettingsResponse autoResponse = autodiscoverService.GetUserSettings(
                "testuser@theusersdomain.com",
                UserSettingName.UserDN,
                UserSettingName.MailboxDN
                );

        }
```

According to MS's documentation, "MailboxDN" is supposed to be the mailbox distinguished name.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/dd633650(v=exchg.80).aspx   - "MailboxDN  - The distinguished name of the mailbox database of the user's mailbox."

However, what I get from the response is: "{[MailboxDN, /o=MyMail/ou=Exchange Administrative Group
/(EYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Configuration/cn=Servers/cn=EXCHANGESERVER/cn=Microsoft Private MDB]}"

The actual message database the user is in is "test1".

Does anyone know how to retrieve this information?

Thanks!

Comment: I've got production code using Exchange Web Services, but, I'm not quite sure what you're trying to get about the user.  When you say mailbox database, do you simply mean all of the users e-mails?

Comment: You can create multiple message databases in exchange. The user's mailbox exists in these message databases.  I need to know which database the user is in on the exchange server.

Comment: The actual term is "mailbox database" not message database...  You can see this in the exchange management console in exchange 2010 under -> recipient config->mailbox->select user->properties.  About right in the middle of the page is "Mailbox database: ..."